# imagecreatefromPHP function or how merge 3 images made by php

Tags: php, image, function

Is it possible to merge 3 images made by php functions? I have image for example http://test.com/image.php and /image2.php and /image3.php and I need one merged image (by coords of course)

Thank you

Comment: if those scripts are dynamically buiding the images, then you should turn them into functions, so you can get the GD/imagick handles of those new images and combine them without having to go through a "building image, save to jpeg, load jpeg" time/memory wasting cycle.

Comment: @MarcB can you give me some example?